# Flag observations before and after a specific value in another column

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Say I have a df:

```
df <- data.frame(flag = c(rep(0, 20)),
                 include = c(rep(1, 20)))
df[c(4,8,16), ]$flag <- 1
df

   flag include
1     0       1
2     0       1
3     0       1
4     1       1
5     0       1
6     0       1
7     0       1
8     1       1
9     0       1
10    0       1
11    0       1
12    0       1
13    0       1
14    0       1
15    0       1
16    1       1
17    0       1
18    0       1
19    0       1
20    0       1
```

What I wish to do is change the `include` flag to 0 if the row is within +/- two rows of a row where `flag == 1`. The result would look like:

```
   flag include
1     0       1
2     0       0
3     0       0
4     1       1
5     0       0
6     0       0
7     0       0
8     1       1
9     0       0
10    0       0
11    0       1
12    0       1
13    0       1
14    0       0
15    0       0
16    1       1
17    0       0
18    0       0
19    0       1
20    0       1
```

I've thought of some 'innovative' (read: inefficient and over complicated) ways to do it but was thinking there must be a simple way I'm overlooking.

Would be nice if the answer was such that I could generalize this to +/- `n` rows, since I have a lot more data and would be looking to potentially search within +/- 10 rows...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
n = 2
# find the row number where flag is one
flag_one = which(df$flag == 1)

# find the index where include needs to be updated
idx = setdiff(outer(flag_one, -n:n, "+"), flag_one)

# update include in place
setDT(df)[idx[idx >= 1 & idx <= nrow(df)], include := 0][]

# or as @Frank commented the last step with base R would be
# df$include[idx[idx >= 1 & idx <= nrow(df)]] = 0

#    flag include
# 1:    0       1
# 2:    0       0
# 3:    0       0
# 4:    1       1
# 5:    0       0
# 6:    0       0
# 7:    0       0
# 8:    1       1
# 9:    0       0
#10:    0       0
#11:    0       1
#12:    0       1
#13:    0       1
#14:    0       0
#15:    0       0
#16:    1       1
#17:    0       0
#18:    0       0
#19:    0       1
#20:    0       1
```

---

Put in a function:

```
update_n <- function(df, n) {
    flag_one = which(df$flag == 1)
    idx = setdiff(outer(flag_one, -n:n, "+"), flag_one)
    df$include[idx[idx >= 1 & idx <= nrow(df)]] = 0
    df
}
```

Comment: Variation - `idx <- which(df$flag==1); df$include[rep(c(-2:-1,1:2),each=length(idx))+idx] <- 0`

Answer (score 2):

There must be another simpler way but the first way which I could think of is using `sapply` and `which`

```
df$include[sapply(which(df$flag == 1) , function(x) c(x-2, x-1, x+1, x+2))] <- 0

df
#   flag include
#1     0       1
#2     0       0
#3     0       0
#4     1       1
#5     0       0
#6     0       0
#7     0       0
#8     1       1
#9     0       0
#10    0       0
#11    0       1
#12    0       1
#13    0       1
#14    0       0
#15    0       0
#16    1       1
#17    0       0
#18    0       0
#19    0       1
#20    0       1
```

We first find out all the indices where `flag` is 1 and then create the required sequence of numbers around each of it and turn that index of `include` to 0.

---

For variable `n` we can do

```
n = 2
df$include[sapply(which(df$flag == 1),function(x) setdiff(seq(x-n, x+n),x))] <- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
replace(x = df$include,
        list = sapply(1:NROW(df), function(i)
            any(df$flag[c(max(1, i-2):max(1, i-1),
                          min(i+1, NROW(df)):min(i+2, NROW(df)))] == 1)), values = 0)
# [1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
```

For `n` rows,

```
replace(x = df$include,
        list = sapply(1:NROW(df), function(i)
            any(df$flag[c(max(1, i-n):max(1, i-1),
                          min(i+1, NROW(df)):min(i+n, NROW(df)))] == 1)), values = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `zoo::rollapply`. To determine if a row is within +/- two rows of a row where `flag == 1`, we check if the maximum `flag` in a window is 1.

We need `rollapply` rather than `rollmax` because we need to specify `partial = T`.

```
is_within_flag_window <- function(flag, n) {
  zoo::rollapply(flag, width = (2 * n) + 1, partial = T, FUN = max) == 1
}

df %>%
  mutate(include = ifelse(flag == 1, 1,
                   ifelse(is_within_flag_window(flag, 2), 0,
                   1)))
```

Comment: Ooo I like this too! Thank you Paul.

Answer (score 0):

Use `which` and `outer`.

```
df$include[outer(which(df$flag==1), -2:2, `+`)] <- 0
```

If flag=1 within one or two positions of each other then restore the ones overwritten at position 0. Note this step is critical in case the "flag" overlaps in a particular range.

```
df$include[which(df$flag==1)] <- 1

   flag include
1     0       1
2     0       0
3     0       0
4     1       1
5     0       0
6     0       0
7     0       0
8     1       1
9     0       0
10    0       0
11    0       1
12    0       1
13    0       1
14    0       0
15    0       0
16    1       1
17    0       0
18    0       0
19    0       1
20    0       1
```

If flag = 1 within one or two rows of the beginning or end of the dataset, R will throw errors. Use this:

```
## assign i for convenience/readability
i <- pmax(1, pmin(nrow(df), outer(which(df$flag==1), -2:2, `+`)))
df$include[i] <- 0
```

Restore 1s as before